# cakephp 3.0 session not supported in safari browser

Tags: php, cakephp, iframe

We have created the application using cakephp 3.0 that an application runs in an Iframe.

Now the problem is **not able to get the session value in the safari browser**.

We have tried this solution added header ('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"') --->It works fine in IE browser

Anyone please, help to get the session value in safari browser

Comment: Try adding session_start();  to the top of your webroot/index.php file.

Comment: @IWillScoop that is horrible advice.

Comment: @IWillScoop We have tried already, but is not working.